# Using jQuery, what is the fastest way to conditionally change a span?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a number of items on a webpage that has something like this:

```
<span id="Joe" class="Status">Pending</span>
<span id="Bill" class="Status">Completed</span>
<span id="Jonh" class="Status">Pending</span>
<span id="Scott" class="Status">Started</span>
```

I want some jquery to change every span that has html() of "Pending" and then change it to "Started" or change it to the Id of that particular span

What is the best way as a selector to get all span with a certain html value and then change them?

Comment: Best way, fastest way, either way have you tried anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:contains()`:

```
$('.Status:contains("Pending")').text('Started');
```

Or alternatively, `filter()`:

```
$('.Status').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Pending';
}).text('Started');
```

<s>I would imagine the `:contains` selector is faster.</s> You can check it yourself at [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com)

**Edit**
I did the test myself. Turns out `filter()` is 64% faster than `:contains` in Chrome at least: http://jsperf.com/contains-vs-filter-rpm

---

> what if i want to have dynamic text (an attribute of the particular span) instead of a hard coded "Started" ??

```
<span class="Status" data-new-text="Started">Pending</span>
<span class="Status" data-new-text="Started">Completed</span>
<span class="Status" data-new-text="Started">Pending</span>
<span class="Status" data-new-text="Started">Started</span>
```

```js
$('.Status').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Pending';
}).each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).data('new-text'));
};
```

Comment: what if i want to have dynamic text (an attribute of the particular span) instead of a hard coded "Started" ??

Comment: You could use a `data-*` attribute to store the new value.

Comment: see my updated question. my issues is not how to store it but rather how to reference it in the .text() item in your answer

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you the `data-*` attribute way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match exactly text

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.Status').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "Pending";
}).html('Started');
```

---

Update

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/contains-vs-filter-rpm/2)  fastest code.

```
$('.Status').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "Pending";
}).text('Started');
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS:

```
var _StatusItems = document.getElementsByClassName('Status');

for (i = 0; i < _StatusItems.length; i++) {
    if (_StatusItems[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Pending') > -1) {
        _StatusItems[i].innerHTML = 'Started';
        continue;
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qCsSc/)**